# Tool to correlate logs by timestamp

Tags: logging, log-files, shell-scripting

I have various log files, some with the same format (webserver + webserver SSL), some with different formats and even different timestamps.

How can I correlate these log files together in a simple console tool?

Bonus question: Some logs might not have a timestamp in every line, such as exception logs - that start with a time stamp, followed by the exception:

```
2012-11-12T10:16:38+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'joinAttribute not implemented' in /var/foo/Bar.php:123
Stack trace:
```

Comment: By "correlate," you mean...?

Comment: Show them in one file, ordered by the date the messages appeared.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Simple Event Correlator (SEC) for this.

http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sounds very interesting. Did you use it? Can you give an example to correlate two logs of the same webserver (same timestamp format etc.) ?

Comment: It's been around for a very long time. It is essentially a very well written perl script. There are tons of examples out there, just give it a good ol' googling :-)

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use it to simply correlate two logs ? I did not find any :-(